# file_get_contents and CURL in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to get the information from the below url:

[API Link](https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/ADX/svc/trading.svc/ListedCompanyOrderBook?listedCompanyID=ADIB)

I tried CURL and file_get_contents in PHP, and I can't get hold of the request.

When I use file_get_contents:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/ADX/svc/trading.svc/ListedCompanyOrderBook?listedCompanyID=ADIB): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

When I use CURL the below message I get:

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgvNP.png)

Below is the file_contents code:

```
<?php 

    $url = "https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/ADX/svc/trading.svc/ListedCompanyOrderBook?listedCompanyID=ADIB";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);

    print_r($data);
?>
```

The other method:

```
<?php 

    $url = "https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/ADX/svc/trading.svc/ListedCompanyOrderBook?listedCompanyID=ADIB";


    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

    print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: I know of some api's that requires setting the user agent, if thats the case with this api, try setting a user agent using this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');`

Comment: Just tried it, and the same error (Request Error)

Comment: Given how aesthetically unappealing the website is, I am not surprised that their API is bugged. The request clearly works when using the web browser but I get `Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/ADX/svc/trading.svc/ListedCompanyOrderBook?listedCompanyID=ADIB): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in...` when using `file_get_contents()` in PHP 5.0.x through 7.2.x. You need to contact the website and have them help you.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @BeingSunny No solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you're runnging this code on http://www.phpfiddle.org/ On that site **curl** is disabled for security reason. If it is your php server then try like this,

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/ADX/svc/trading.svc/ListedCompanyOrderBook?listedCompanyID=ADIB",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: It is running on my localhost. It is still showing the same error.

Comment: Try to  set `allow_url_fopen` to 1 in your  php.ini file